# Can someone explain the meaning of this regex line?

Tags: c++

I have trouble understanding the syntax and the overall meaning of this line of the code.

```
bool isValidEmail(string email) {
        return regex_match(email, regex("\\w*\\.?\\w*\\@(hotmail.com|outlook.com|fit.ba)"));
    }
```

Comment: What about it is giving you trouble?

Comment: Google up regular expression syntax

Comment: this "\\w*\\.?\\w*\\" part @NathanOliver

Comment: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/q9JoGK/2) gives good explanation and allows to test it.

Comment: Plug it into https://regex101.com/ for an explanation. `\w` represents a word character.

Comment: I have idea about c++ regex. But at first sight out looks like a word, and optionally a dot, followed by another word ... should be possible to find out using Google.

Comment: btw, validating email via regex address is more complicated than that (as email can contain special charaters too).

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression terms `\w*\.?\w*` means *zero or more word characters followed by an optional dot followed by zero or more word characters* where "word character" means A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _.

As a note, this means `@hotmail.com` matches. So does `.@hotmail.com` and `x.@hotmail.com` which is probably wrong.

Comment: second part is also problematic with un-escaped dot.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right, that's actually another problem. `@hotmailxcom` is valid too.